# TypeScript: class-validator's validate function not working as initially expected for array of JSON objects?

Tags: json, typescript, class-validator

I have a service class called Config Service, which is responsible for loading up an array of JSON objects, and validating them for errors based on my class-validator criteria.

I've got it working via one method `validateOrRejectArray`, but originally thought it would work via `validateOrReject_array`.

Here is my code:

**mapPreset.ts**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Expose, Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsNumber, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

export class MapPreset {
    @Expose()
    @IsNumber()
    readonly id: number;
    @Expose()
    @ValidateNested()
    @Type(() => MapSetup)
    readonly mapSetUp: MapSetup;

    constructor(id: number, mapSetUp: MapSetup) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mapSetUp = mapSetUp;
    }
}

export class MapSetup {
    @Expose()
    readonly longitude: number;
    @Expose()
    readonly latitude: number;
    @Expose()
    readonly zoom: number;
}
```

**utils.ts**

```
import { ValidationError, validate } from 'class-validator';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { ClassType } from 'class-transformer/ClassTransformer';


export function loadArrayFromJson<T>(json: Record<string, unknown>[], classType: ClassType<T>): T[] {
    return plainToClass(classType, json, { excludeExtraneousValues: true });
}

export async function validateOrRejectArray<T>(inputs: T[]): Promise<ValidationError[]> {
    const errors: ValidationError[] = [];
    for (const input of inputs) {
        const validationErrors = await validate(input as Record<string, unknown>);
        errors.push(...validationErrors);
    }
    console.log('validateOrRejectArray Validation errors: ', errors);
    return errors;
}

export async function validateOrReject_array<T>(inputs: T[]): Promise<ValidationError[]> {
    const errors = await validate(inputs);
    
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        console.log('validateOrReject_array Validation errors: ', errors);
    } else {
        console.log('validateOrReject_array No validation errors', errors);
    }

    return errors;
}
```

I have a file containing an array of JSON objects:
**Note, the "id" value should be a number according to the dto, so entries 1 and 2 should be erroneous here**

**mapPresets.json**

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "mapSetUp": {
            "longitude": -5.914829367454222,
            "latitude": 54.60483348272094,
            "zoom": 15
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "mapSetUp": {
            "longitude": -7.914829367454222,
            "latitude": 70.60483348272093,
            "zoom": 15
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "mapSetUp": {
            "longitude": -8.191482936745421,
            "latitude": 70.60483348272093,
            "zoom": 15
        }
    }
]
```

And finally,

**config-service.ts**

```
import { loadArrayFromJson, validateOrRejectArray, validateOrReject_array } from '../utilities/utils';
import { MapPreset } from './mapPreset';
import mapPresetsJson from './mapPresets.json';

export class ConfigService {
    readonly mapPresets: MapPreset[];

    constructor() {
        this.mapPresets = loadArrayFromJson(mapPresetsJson, MapPreset);
        console.log('ConfigService: ', this.mapPresets);
        validateOrRejectArray(this.mapPresets);
        validateOrReject_array(this.mapPresets);
    }

    public getMapPresets(): MapPreset[] {
        return this.mapPresets;
    }

    public getMapPresetById(id: number): MapPreset | undefined {
        return this.mapPresets.find((mp: MapPreset) => mp.id === id);
    }
}
```

`validateOrRejectArray` tells me that I have a ValidationError array of length 2 (what I would expect!)

But `validateOrReject_array` tells me I have 0 ValidationErrors.

I'm unsure why, is it as simple as the fact that [class-validator's](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) `validate` function does not support arrays? I kept hearing from a source that it did work for arrays hence my confusion, and the documentation is a little bit scarce in some places so I was unsure.